# NameError: name 'xone' is not defined (Dont look on Russian words, it's not responsible for anything

Tags: python

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DS", line 22, in 
    print ( " x1 = " + str(xone))
NameError: name 'xone' is not defined

## a,b,c и D

a = float( input( "Введите чиcло a: "))

b = float( input( "Введите чиcло b: "))

c = float( input( "Введите чиcло c: "))

## Finding D

D = (b * b) - 4 * a * c

## Finding x1, x2 and print this

if D > 0:

xone = ( -b + (D / D)) / 2 * a

xtwo = ( -b - (D / D)) / 2 * a

print ( " D = " + str(D))

print ( " x1 = " + str(xone))

print ( " x2 = " + str(xtwo))

## Finding x

if D == 0:

x = -b / (2 * a)

print ( " D = " + str(D))

print ( " x = " + str(x))

if D < 0:

print ( " D = " + str(D))

print ( "Dont have x1 and x2! ")

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: always put error in question, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: write in English. Use special button to format code - indentations are very important.

Comment: again: put error message in question, not in comment.  It will be more readable and more people will see it

Comment: if  `D <= 0` then  `xone = ` is not executed and `xone` is not created so you can't print it. You have to use `else: xone = "other value"` to assing some value when `D <= 0`. Or assign some value to `xone = "some value"` at start as default value.

Comment: BTW: when you edit question then there is button `{}` to format code. Your code without indentations is useless.

Comment: maybe you should change indentations and use `print( ... xone)` inside `if  D > 0:` when `xone` exists.

Comment: furas thank`s for trying help :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a problem here

```
if D > 0:
    xone = ( -b + (D / D)) / 2 * a
```

In cases where D is not greater than 0, there is no definition for xone. So when you get to line 22 at `print ( " x1 = " + str(xone))`, xone has no definition, and therefore gives you this NameError.

Suggestion:

```
if D > 0:
    xone = ( -b + (D / D)) / 2 * a 
else:
    xone = {something else}
```

Suggestion 2, keeping the code style as is:

```
D = (b * b) - 4 * a * c

if D > 0:
    xone = ( -b + (D / D)) / 2 * a 
    xtwo = ( -b - (D / D)) / 2 * a 
    print ( " D = " + str(D))
    print ( " x1 = " + str(xone))
    print ( " x2 = " + str(xtwo))

elif D < 0:
    x = 0
    print("something")

else:
    # This will also execute if D is a string or something else, which potentially causes problems with the next line
    xthree = -b / (2 * a)
    print ( " D = " + str(D))
    print ( " x3 = " + str(xthree ))
```

Comment: can i ask, what i can write here {something else} ?

Comment: I think it's better if you take a step back and ask what you want this program to do. You've got three checks of `D` where you ask the program to define xone, x, or print a statement depending on the value of 'D'. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate, hang on.

Comment: this program would calculate the Discriminant

Comment: D - Discriminant,  x it`s a roots

Comment: xone - x1 xtwo - x2